# Canvas, JS torch effect: Fill background with a picture

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I have an animated flame drawn on canvas.

It is supposed to create the torch effect which lights up the background of the page.

It all works fine until I don't want to change background of canvas to a picture. It doesn't work at all.

When I set background through CSS - my flame colors whole canvas.

Can somebody help me change background of canvas to a picture without destroying the effect?

Here's a [link](https://codepen.io/judyhopps/pen/xXQVbx) to codepen.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //Make the canvas occupy the full page
  var W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;

  var particles = [];
  var mouse = {};

  //Lets create some particles now
  var particle_count = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < particle_count; i++) {
    particles.push(new particle());
  }

  //finally some mouse tracking
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', track_mouse, false);

  function track_mouse(e) {
    //since the canvas = full page the position of the mouse 
    //relative to the document will suffice
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
  }

  function particle() {
    //speed, life, location, life, colors
    //speed.x range = -2.5 to 2.5 
    //speed.y range = -15 to -5 to make it move upwards
    //lets change the Y speed to make it look like a flame
    this.speed = {
      x: -2.5 + Math.random() * 5,
      y: -15 + Math.random() * 10
    };
    //location = mouse coordinates
    //Now the flame follows the mouse coordinates
    if (mouse.x && mouse.y) {
      this.location = {
        x: mouse.x,
        y: mouse.y
      };
    } else {
      this.location = {
        x: W / 2,
        y: H / 2
      };
    }
    //radius range = 10-30
    this.radius = 10 + Math.random() * 20;
    //life range = 20-30
    this.life = 20 + Math.random() * 10;
    this.remaining_life = this.life;
    //colors
    this.r = 74;
    this.g = 77;
    this.b = 84;
    //  this.r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    //  this.g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    //  this.b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
  }


  function draw() {
    //Painting the canvas black
    //Time for lighting magic
    //particles are painted with "lighter"
    //In the next frame the background is painted normally without blending to the 
    //previous framevar im = new Image();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //  var im = new Image();
    //  im.src = "./background.jpg";
    //  im.onload = function (){
    //  ctx.drawImage(im, W, H);
    //  }

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //  var src    = "../images/background.jpg";
    //     var img    = new Image();
    //     img.src    = src;
    //     $(img).load(function() {
    //   var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    //   ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    //   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    //    });

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      ctx.beginPath();
      //changing opacity according to the life.
      //opacity goes to 0 at the end of life of a particle
      p.opacity = Math.round(p.remaining_life / p.life * 100) / 100
      //a gradient instead of white fill
      var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.location.x, p.location.y, 0, p.location.x, p.location.y, p.radius);
      //   p.r = 128;
      //   p.g = 34;
      //   p.b = 34;
      p.r = 255;
      p.g = 69;
      p.b = 0;
      gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", " + p.opacity + ")");
      gradient.addColorStop(0.2, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", " + p.opacity + ")");
      gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", 0)");
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.arc(p.location.x, p.location.y, p.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.fill();

      //lets move the particles
      p.remaining_life--;
      p.radius--;
      p.location.x += p.speed.x;
      p.location.y += p.speed.y;

      //regenerate particles
      if (p.remaining_life < 0 || p.radius < 0) {
        //a brand new particle replacing the dead one
        particles[i] = new particle();
      }
    }

    ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  }

  setInterval(draw, 33);

  /****************************TORCH LIGHT*********************************/

  //
  //canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  //  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
  //  running = false;
  //});

  function update(e) {
    //set e as .torch class
    //var element = document.getElementsByClassName("torch"); 
    var x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
    var y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY


    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px')
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY', y + 'px')
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)

  // lets light up canvas element after click

  // function change_the_before_attribute(other_background) {
  // other_background.className="torch after-click";
  //}
  $(function() {
    $(".torch").click(function() {
      $(".torch").addClass(".torch .after-click");
    });
  });
  //changes background of body
  //$(function () {
  //    $("body").click(function () {
  //        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255,0,0,.95)');
  //    });
  //});


}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  /* background: url("../images/background.jpg");*/
}

.torch {
  /*  cursor: none;*/
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}

:root:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%)
}

.torch .after-click:before {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="torch">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: How about adding the background to the wrapping div, for example ".torch"?

Comment: When I do that my flame colors background; I added background to .torch and changed ctx.fillStyle = "black"; to ctx.fillStyle = "transparent"; and it doest't look good

Comment: Please don't link to external resources.  Bring you code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code after setting the `ctx` variable:

```
 var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499955618064-79cd8e8d8672?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&s=13c8ccb1b33e610c3e8d6a4094dc85fd';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
  }
```

Then in the draw method add the following line:

```
ctx.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
```

Adding the background to the canvas in pure CSS won't do the trick. Adding it as an image object will. This code initializes the image and draws in to the canvas if it was loaded. In the draw method we re-paint the image again to the canvas each frame.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You very much! I actually helped myself by adding: ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out"; before filling my canvas black and it works fine. Now I am dealing with another problem. As long as my canvas is on top of the page- everything is working fine. If I add a div before canvas- torch stops to move. I know that there is a problem with mouse-tracking, because: function track_mouse(e)
 {
  mouse.x = e.pageX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY;
 } works only if canvas = full page. I can't manage to fix this when there is anything above canvas.

Comment: I tried something like this: function track_mouse(e) { 
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left;            
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top;  
  console.log(x, y);
 }
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', track_mouse, false); but it doesn't work despite console seems to return proper values of coordinates. Maybe You have some suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure. I always use event.stageX and event.stageY, maybe this helps. I think you should add another question for that.

Comment: Luckily I managed to fix it; changed my function to something like this:  //mouse tracking while canvas != full page
    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', track_mouse, false);
    
    function track_mouse(evt)
 {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        mouse.x = mousePos.x + 20;
        mouse.y = mousePos.y;
        console.log('Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y);
 }